# The interpretation of one line Javascript code

Tags: javascript

What is the interpretation of this line in Javascript.

```
var x[],matrix[],n;
...
n = (matrix = x) && matrix.length;
```

Despite I searched for it, I couldn't find any tips.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try running it? What was the outcome? What surprised you?

Comment: n will be a boolean value if matrix is an array of length and x is an array that equals x

Comment: `matrix = x;
n = matrix && matrix.length;`

Comment: @FastSnail yes - this wilol be exactly equivalent (though you miss a semicolumn after `x`). It's also the more sensible way to write it, IMO - the shorthand assignment+evaluation of the assignment is annoying to maintain.

Comment: @Kosch: The odds of `n` ending up being a boolean with the code above are quite low. `x` would have to be something like `{length: true}`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed. Although if `x` is `false` then and only then would `n` "legitimately" be set to a boolean.

Comment: @Vld: Good point, that's another way you'd end up with a boolean in `n`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I thought 0 was falsey, so if the array didn't have any values (length 0) we'd come up falsey.

Comment: @ user: I hadn't seen your edit added `var x[],matrix[],n;` to the top. That's invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @Kosch `0` is falsey but the `&&` doesn't return you a boolean but the _value_. If you do `var a = 0 && 1` then `a = 0`. The way `&&` works is "is the left value truthy - if no return it, if yes, return the right value". Conversely `var a = 0 || 1` is `a=1` because the OR works in a similar way - it gives you the value, not a boolean.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder, i saw those parens and thought of 'if shorthand' without recognizing the equals was an assignment; and not a conditional check of equality.  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does this:

1. Assigns the value of `x` to `matrix`; the result of the `matrix = x` expression is the value that was assigned (this is true of all assignment expressions). Let's call that value "x-value". I don't want to call it `x` from here on out, because `x` is only evaluated once.
2. If x-value is *truthy*<sup>1</sup> (coerces to true), it assigns `matrix.length` to `n`; otherwise, assigns x-value to `n`.

So for instance, if `x` is `[]`, the code sets `matrix` to point to the same empty array `x` does and sets `n` to `0` (`matrix.length` after the assignment). Other examples *(I'd written these before you edited your question)*: If `x` is `"foo"`, it sets `matrix` to `"foo"` and sets `n` to `3` (the `length` of `matrix`). If `x` is `""` (a falsy value), it sets `matrix` to `""` *and* sets `n` to `""`. If `x` is `{foo:"bar"}`, it sets `matrix` to refer to that same object and sets `n` to `undefined` (since the object has no `length` property). You get the idea.

#2 above comes about because `&&` is not just a simple logical AND operator. `a && b` works like this:

1. Evaluate `a` to get its value; let's call that a-value
2. If a-value is *falsy*, the result of the `&&` operator is a-value
3. Otherwise, evaluate `b` and make that the result of the `&&` operator

---

<sup>1</sup> "Truthy" values are any values that aren't "falsy." The falsy values are `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.

Comment: Useful resource for reference when talking about truthy/falsey values in JavaScript: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We can interpret it as some pseudocode like this:

```
var x[],matrix[],n;
...
matrix = x
if(x is not in [null, false, 0, undefined, "NaN",""])
      n = matrix.length
else
      n = x
```

Answer (score 1):

`(matrix = x)` is the assignment operation of `x` into a variable `matrix`. Here `x` is an array, hence the result of this operation gives a truthy value, and hence the later part takes place.

E.g. if

```
var x, matrix = [], n;
n = (matrix = x) && matrix.length;
```

won't work as the `(matrix = x)` is a falsy operation. `n` gets assigned `undefined` (because that's the value `x` has).

Comment: "`(matrix = x)` is a falsy operation. n stays `undefined`" also worth noting that this is misleading - `n` doesn't _stay_ undefined, it gets assigned the `undefined` value. It's a small but important difference because if `x` was equal to `""`, then `n` would also be `""` afterwards or if `n` had a value, it'd now be `undefined`. The assignment changes the value, only in your specific example it would change it to the same value as before.

Comment: Correct @Vld Greatly pointed. My bad. If the operation `(matrix = x)` returns a falsy value, `n` gets assigned to an `undefined` value. Will update.